# tar --list only top level files and folders

Tags: grep, osx, tar

using `tar --list --file=x` will list all files and folders.
I am just looking to list the top level files and folders

does anyone know how to do that?

alternatively, does anyone know how to list only the top level files, but all folders including subfolders? Maybe with grep somehow?

update: looking for something that works on most nix flavors including MacOS.

Comment: This approach may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116375/6216002

Answer (score 32):

The following method works for me to show only the top level files and directory names,

```
tar --exclude='./*/*' -tvf ttt.tar.gz
```

The following method shows one more level,

```
tar --exclude='./*/*/*' -tvf ttt.tar.gz
```

Directories are listed with a trailing slash.

If the list does not start with a dot or slash, you should use another pattern, for example

```
tar --exclude='*/*' -tvf ttt.tar.gz
```

for only the top level directory and

```
tar --exclude='*/*/*' -tvf ttt.tar.gz
```

for one more level.

Comment: On `tar` 1.30+ this didn't work. I had to use `--exclude='*/*'` for top level directories.

Comment: @TejasPendse, If I understand correctly, this is what I describe in the second half of the answer: "If the list does not start with a dot or slash, you should use another pattern, for example `tar --exclude='*/*' -tvf ttt.tar.gz`". (I have tar (GNU tar) 1.34 now.)

Comment: Works, but is slow for large tar files since it has to apply the exclusion filter on all files in the archive file. :(

Comment: I found this more cleaner,
`tar -tf archive.tar | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | uniq`